# Creating side by side bar plot for 2 continuous and one categorical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a data set with 2 continuous and 1 categorical variables. I want to have side by side bar plot for comparing the continuous variables and the categorical variable on X axis in R. I used melt from the reshape2 package but it is not coming as I expected.

[image: This is the data I have 2 cont, 1 cat vars]

Comment: Please include the code you have tried, and show your data as text rather than as an image

Comment: "side by side' -- Are you looking for two graph next to each other? if so `par` function can be used to set `mfrow` as `c(1, 2)` (2 columns) where 2 graphs will be displayed.